# Code Error!? Why there is two different answer?

Tags: codeblocks, pow

I have run a quite simple program in my pc but it's giving me the wrong answer. When I copied the code to an online IDE, the answer is correct. I am using CodeBlocks. Where is the problem.?

Online IDE link: https://ideone.com/yKV5NV

This is the image of the result in my PC:

[image: Image of the Result in my pc]

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int x=5,k=2,ans;
    ans=(pow(x,k+1));
    printf("%d",ans);

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I think maybe because of the double data type rounding error. But why it is happening everytime. If I am right, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because of floating point number representation that can't hold "exact" value that you expect. It happens every time because of same input data, so why wouldn't it? Regarding how to fix it, there is nothing to fix really, it's simply the way floating point numbers are working.